# Perché a volte si scrive l'accento acuto sulla "i" o sulla "u"?

Tags: orthography, accents

Ho osservato che alcuni autori usano l'accento acuto sulla "i" o sulla "u" nelle loro opere letterarie, cioè scrivono "í" o "ú" invece di "ì" o "ù". Perché si fa questo?

Ecco alcuni esempi tratti da due libri pubblicati da Einaudi:

- Cesare Pavese. *La luna e i falò*:

> «Lo starnuto di un cane, ***piú*** vicino, e un ***rotolío*** di pietre mi fece
>   saltare.»

- Primo Levi. *Se questo è un uomo*:

> «Era ***cosí***: per la prima volta dal giorno del mio arresto, mi trovavo
>   libero, senza custodi armati, senza reticolati fra me e la mia casa.
>
> A forse quattrocento metri dal campo, giacevano le patate: un tesoro.
>   Due fosse lunghissime, piene di patate, e ricoperte di terra alternata
>   con paglia a difesa dal gelo. Nessuno sarebbe ***piú*** morto di fame.»

Comment: "sé" pronome personale io lo pronuncio con la "e" aperta. So che si scrive con l'accento acuto. Sbaglio allora la pronuncia?

Comment: @ElsaDalGesso: Sì, purtroppo stai sbagliando la pronuncia (vedi anche [qui](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=12384&r=430), per esempio). È comune, soprattutto al nord, pronunciare aperte alcune vocali che in italiano standard sono chiuse, come in “perché”. Ma soprattutto stai sbagliando a intervenire scrivendo questa come se fosse una risposta alla domanda su “i” e “u”.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Prima di tutto, non sono gli autori a decidere, ma le norme redazionali della casa editrice (la più famosa a usare gli accenti acuti su “i” e “u” è l'Einaudi), come per quali virgolette («» o “”) usare, come impostare i dialoghi (virgolette, trattini etc.) e altre minuzie tra il tipografico e lo stilistico.

In secondo luogo, il motivo per cui alcuni sostengono che sia meglio usare l'accento acuto su queste due vocali è che ognuna di esse corrisponde a un unico fonema vocalico (a differenza di “e” e “o”), e questo fonema è chiuso (a differenza di quello della “a”). In altre parole, in italiano non c'è per esempio la “i aperta” dell'inglese *bit*.
Data questa unicità, la convenzione prevalente (che si è fossilizzata con la diffusione delle macchine per scrivere moderne e poi delle tastiere per computer) consiste nell'usare su tutte le vocali l'accento grave, tranne per le “e” e “o” chiuse; invece la convenzione minoritaria è quella che hai notato, con “í” e “ú”.

Comment: Questo mi sembra molto curioso. In catalano abbiamo anche accenti acuti e accenti gravi che usiamo seguendo delle regole di accentazione, tenendo conto del suono aperto o chiuso della vocale che va accentata per sapere se l'accento grafico deve essere acuto o grave. Così l'accento sulla "a" è sempre grave, sulla "i" e sulla "u" è sempre acuto, mentre sulla "e" e sulla "o" può essere grave o acuto.

Comment: @Charo In Italia l'accento è stato, per secoli, solo nella forma ora chiamata “grave”. La distinzione tra “è” e “é” è piuttosto recente (seconda metà del ventesimo secolo). Nota che l'accento grafico su “ò”, quando è obbligatorio, è sempre grave, perché non esistono parole italiane terminanti in “o tonica chiusa”.

Comment: Evidenzio [questa risposta](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_453.html) sul sito della Treccani e questo interessante [articolo](http://www.achyra.org/infarinato/files/iu.pdf)

Answer (score 14):

L'accento grafico italiano deriva da un apostrofo che indicava la caduta di una sillaba. In Dante si trovano sia *virtute* sia *virtù*. Ovviamente le esigenze metriche spiegano l'uso delle due varianti, ma è evidente che ai suoi tempi la sillaba finale non era ancora definitivamente caduta. Il pennacchio si spostò sulla vocale, probabilmente per distinguere i due usi dell'apostrofo e divenne essenzialmente obbligatorio segnare il pennacchio su tutte le parole ossitone.

La forma grafica in stampa è stata per secoli quella dell'accento “grave”, senza distinzioni. Solo nel ventesimo secolo, credo su influsso del francese, si cominciò a distinguere tra accento grave e acuto sulla “e finale” per indicarne la pronuncia aperta o chiusa. Come ho già fatto notare, in [questa edizione del 1830 dei *Promessi Sposi*](http://books.google.it/books?id=7UkTAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=promessi%20sposi&hl=it&sa=X&ei=En4CU_OqDYLhywPK_oCwAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=promessi%20sposi&f=false) non compaiono accenti acuti, ma è facile controllare che lo stesso accade per libri molto posteriori (per esempio [questo di Pirandello del 1922](http://books.google.it/books?id=0UxdAAAAMAAJ&dq=pirandello%20il%20fu%20mattia%20pascal&hl=it&source=gbs_navlinks_s) dove c'è sempre *perchè*).

Sulle macchine per scrivere vendute in Italia comparivano queste vocali accentate: *à è é ì ò ù* (solo minuscole). Nessuna parola propriamente italiana ha la “o finale” chiusa; anche i prestiti meno recenti dal francese come *borderò* hanno pronuncia aperta mentre in francese sarebbe chiusa.

La storia degli accenti in catalano è diversa. Non so chi abbia cominciato per primo a segnare gli accenti: catalani, castigliani o portoghesi; sta di fatto che le regole sulla segnatura dell'accento sono molto simili nelle tre lingue. In castigliano non c'è la distinzione tra vocali aperte e chiuse, che invece esiste in catalano, che ha un sistema vocalico molto simile a quello dell'italiano. In particolare, il catalano deve distinguere tra *ò* e *ó* in posizione intermedia.

Qualcuno sostiene che anche in italiano l'accento dovrebbe essere acuto sulle vocali chiuse (*i* e *u*), con buoni argomenti. Tuttavia la tradizione è diversa. Alcune case editrici hanno come prassi editoriale quella di adoperare *í* e *ú*, altre seguono la tradizione con la sola eccezione per *è*/*é*.

Si può notare che il Touring Club Italiano usa, nelle sue carte, sempre l'accento acuto (per esempio *Venézia*) per indicare semplicemente la vocale tonica, senza prendere posizione sulla pronuncia aperta o chiusa: i veneti dicono senza alcuna esitazione *Venèzia* e un *Venézia* sarebbe accolto con alzate di sopracciglio se non con risatine.

Comment: Dato che hai menzionato il catalano, aggiungo questo commento. In questo [libro in catalano del XIX secolo](http://books.google.es/books?id=_igVAAAAYAAJ&hl=es&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false), ci sono accenti acuti e gravi, ma usati in modo molto diverso a come si fa oggi. Le regole ortografiche del catalano attuale sono di Pompeu Fabra (1913). A proposito: in catalano abbiamo anche parole ossitone terminanti in "*ó*" (“o tonica chiusa”).

Comment: @Charo Ho il sospetto che le attuali norme siano state influenzate da quelle del castigliano, almeno per quanto riguarda gli accenti.

Comment: Hai ragione, ma le regole di accentazione hanno anche importanti differenze col castigliano.

Answer (score 7):

Come qualcuno ha giustamente notato, in italiano la "i" e "u" hanno solo suono chiuso quindi l'accento corretto sarebbe quello acuto; gli accenti sono stati "semplificati" prima dai tipografi (al tempo del piombo) e poi definitivamente standardizzati dalle macchine per scrivere, che hanno normalizzato l'accento grave anche dove non c'entrava nulla. C'è stata opposizione a questo piccolo scempio e in tempi recenti un grande linguista come il Gabrielli ancora vi si opponeva strenuamente. Con poco successo, purtroppo.

Comment: Perché l'accento corretto sarebbe acuto, quando per secoli non c'è stata distinzione e si adoperava sempre quello grave? Un segno è un segno e non ha di per sé alcun significato, se non quello che gli si affibbia. Nella mia risposta dico che ci sarebbero buone ragioni per usare l'accento acuto su “i” e ”u”, ma non vedo motivi per andare contro una tradizione secolare; viceversa, la distinzione dell'accento sulla “e” è utile.

Comment: @egreg *la distinzione dell'accento sulla "e" è utile*. Su questo si può discutere, non mi sembra una verità assoluta.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Diciamo *sarebbe utile se venisse insegnata*. Magari i lombardi smetterebbero di dire *perchè*. `;-)`

Comment: Moltissimo era lasciato al caso e più o meno casuale (dettata dalle abitudini dei tipografi e dei fabbricanti di tastiere) è la ragione dell'uso dominante dell'accento grave sulle "i" e le "u", nonostante il loro suono sia sempre chiuso.

Il suono aperto o chiuso è rilevante, perché se oggi mettiamo l'accento acuto sulle "e" e le "o" chiuse, e quello grave sulle aperte, vuol dire che abbiamo attribuito ai due tipi di accento un significato convenzionale preciso.

Detto questo non siamo certamente davanti all'esempio peggiore di un uso sbagliato che diventa dominante...  :)

Answer (score 1):

Sospettavo, che il passaggio dall'accento acuto a quello grave sulla "i" fosse dettato più dalla diffusione globale di tastiere che non da ragioni linguistiche. E questa francamente non la trovo una buona ragione. 
In una grammatica normativa del 1959 ho trovato come regola fissa che l'accento sulla "i" deve essere acuto. Proprio per la ragione fonetica che in italiano la "i" viene pronunciata esclusivamente chiusa.
E quando scrivo a mano, continuo a seguire questa regola dell'italiano che le tastiere purtroppo mi impongono di non usare.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE!

Comment: Qual è questa grammatica di cui stai parlando? Potresti dare piú dettagli?