# Qual è l'uso di "sì" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Nel racconto *La conchiglia* di Marisa Madieri ho letto (uso l'[ortografia della casa editrice Einaudi](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/2344/707), che ha pubblicato la versione che ho letto):

> «Mio padre li avrebbe legati assieme, sí da formare una semplice e solida imbarcazione per la pesca.»

Non capisco bene come viene usato il vocabolo "sì" in questa frase. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

“Sì” è, in questo caso, la forma abbreviata di “così”, e quindi in questa frase ha il senso di “in modo da”. In Dante e altri scrittori classici si trova spesso; oggi è un po' ricercato, a parte nella frase fatta “fare sì che” cioè, appunto, “fare in modo che”.

Comment: Aggiungo che esiste anche il [sicché](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sicche/), molto usato in Toscana.